# trying to limit typeahead options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead

So I have a typeahead. You have a schedule and you start typing a class and the dropdown on the input will show what classes are available in your schedule. However, if they are not in the schedule, I don't want the user to be able to submit it. Right now you can just type garbage and even though it's not in the dropdown for the typeahead, you can still submit it. This is my code:

```
$.each(schedule.classes, function(value) {
  if(value !== $('.optimizeScheduleClasses :input').val()){
    $errorMessage.text('Your selection do not match the class(es) available in the current schedule!');
    $errorMessage.show();                       
    error = true;                       
    return false;
  }
});
```

however, this is just giving the error whether they put in garbage or an actual class in the schedule. I also tried this:

```
var schedule = schedule.content.get();
$.each(schedule.classes, function(index, value){
  if(schedule.classes[index] !== value){
    $errorMessage.text('Your selection does not match the class(es) in the current schedule!');
    $errorMessage.show();                       
    error = true;                       
    return false;
  } else {
    error=false;
  }
});
```

but this lets every class get selected, even classes outside of the schedule's options. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

`<script id="ScheduleClassPopup" class="partial" type="text/html">
     <div class="control-group optimizeScheduleClasses modal-body-row" data-index="{{rowNum}}">`

Comment: Does it give you an error with the original code even if you put in something valid? Not so sure about the logic of the typeahead...

Comment: the first way will error no matter what. the second way will accept anything, @Gnijuohz

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I meant...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code here is not quite correct:

```
 if(schedule.classes[index] !== value)
```

They will always be equal according to the documentation for [each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). You should compare `schedule.classes[index]` with `$('.optimizeScheduleClasses :input').val()` which is exactly what the original code does.

I think it's better to do something inside `submit`. If you have a `$("#form").submit(function(){});` somewhere then try to do something like checking if the input is valid or not inside that. A simple idea is to use a global variable(not so good though) to indicate the error then check it inside the submit function. In your example you can check the variable `error`.

But I think it's perfectly fine to allow invalid input. IMHO returning a message telling the user there is no such class in his/her schedule is not an inferior option.

And for the original code, assuming it **inside another function** then try this:

```
$.each(schedule.classes, function(index, value) {
  if(value == $('.optimizeScheduleClasses :input').val()){                       
    return true;
  }
});
$errorMessage.text('Your selection do not match the class(es) available in the current schedule!');
$errorMessage.show();                       
error = true;
return false;
```

Comment: i think another issue is that $('.optimizeScheduleClasses :input').val()) returns three parts of the schedule [time, class, day]. I need to just get the class part. do you know how to just get the class part? I've tried to do different things, but this line I'm unfamiliar with how the syntax is working in javascript. A friend helped with this line.

Comment: Also, the way your solution is, the error message will show everytime, for every class

Comment: @user2847749 could you please post some of the related html? It's hard to say what's going on without that.

Comment: I couldn't remember how to format the html but I got it and added it to the OP @Gnijuohz